# JSONCPP to Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, jsoncpp

I am having some trouble getting the JSONCPP Library into Visual Studio.

I have downloaded the library I am just unsure how to import it into my project and use it in my c++ code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it a static library? DLL? Or do you have to compile it yourself?

Comment: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp

Comment: I basically do not know to take this library and use it in c++.

Comment: The documentation is actually quite good -- I suggest following the instructions for [generating an amalgamated .h & .cpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp#generating-amalgamated-source-and-header). Then you can just drop them into your project (`Add->Existing Item` in VS). After that all you need to do is include the header wherever you want to use jsoncpp.

Comment: I did that but I am getting a error:
"cannot open include file: 'json/json.h' no such file or directory".

Comment: Well, does that file exist on disk? Where did you put the `json.h` file relative to the file you're including it in?

Comment: I did exactly what you mentioned.  I added each of the files as existing items.  The .h files json.h and json-forwards.h are in the header files jsoncpp.cpp is in the source files folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64355/discussion-between-blakepeterman-and-cameron).

Answer (score 4):

To fix the error "cannot open include file: 'json/json.h' no such file or directory", you need to add Include directory to your project as following:

-Right click on your project -> Properties.  Under C/C++ ->General ->Additional Include Directories, add C:\your-directory-to-jsoncpp-master\include (e.g. C:\user1\jsoncpp-master\include).